# Express JS - Database Timeout

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I try to extract sql query excution to another file to avoid code repetition and I have problem with timeouts while execution.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

const connectionData = {
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '****',
    database: 'app'
};

module.exports = {
    doQuery: function (query) {
        var connection = mysql.createConnection(connectionData);
        connection.connect(function(error) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
                return {
                    status: 502,
                    data: {error: {code: 502, message: "Database connection error."}}
                };
            }
        });
        connection.query(query, function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
                return {
                    status: 500,
                    data: {error: {code: 500, message: "Internal server error"}}
                };
            } else if (results.length) {
                return {
                    status: 200,
                    data: {data: results}
                };
            } else {
                return {
                    status: 404,
                    data: {error: {code: 404, message: "Not Found"}}
                };
            }
        });
        connection.end(function(error) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
                return {
                    status: 502,
                    data: {error: {code: 502, message: "Database connection error."}}
                };
            }
        });
        return {
            status: 504,
            data: {error: {code: 504, message: "Gateway Timeout"}}
        };
    }
}
```

And my usage:

```
router.get('/products', function (req, res, next) {
    var response = sqlHandler.doQuery('SELECT * FROM product');
    return res.status(response.status).json(response.data);
});
```

Any idea?
The same code directly in router.get works properly. In debug mode I can see that after connection.connect connection.status is disconnected, but error is not logged.

Answer (score 0):

### **TLDR**

You do not provide a callback function to receive the data asynchronously. But do not use callbacks, use promises with async await instead to avoid callback hell.

### Long Version

**Callbacks**

Your function call to `doQuery` is synchronous and the only returned synchronous data is:

```
 return {
        status: 504,
        data: {error: {code: 504, message: "Gateway Timeout"}}
    };
```

To make this code work you need to provide a callback function parameter to `doQuery` which can be called asynchronously within each anonymous callback function of the connection methods plus for the gateway timeout and you need to nest all the method calls into the anonymous callback functions:

`connection.query` needs to be nested within the callback function of `connection.connect` and `connection.end` needs to be nested within the callback function of `connection.connect`.

This adds lots of indentation, reduces readability and makes maintaining the code really hard. This is what we call callback hell: http://callbackhell.com/

Also usually there is a pool of persistent connections to the database, which is used for a query. This means, the code for opening and closing the connection should not be part of each query. The connection pool initialisation should be usually done at startup of the server.

I added some example code for illustration, how this would look like. But there is a better solution, see below.

```
router.get('/products', function (req, res, next) {
    sqlHandler.doQuery('SELECT * FROM product', function(response) {
        return res.status(response.status).json(response.data);
    });
});



module.exports = {
doQuery: function (query, cb) {
    var connection = mysql.createConnection(connectionData);
    connection.connect(function(error) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return {
                status: 502,
                data: {error: {code: 502, message: "Database connection error."}}
            };
        }

        connection.query(query, function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
                cb({
                    status: 500,
                    data: {error: {code: 500, message: "Internal server error"}}
                });
                return;
            }...
```

}

**Promises**

Promises and the syntactic sugar async/await changes the code structure so the asynchronous code can be read the same synchronous code.

Or instead you could `util.promisify` to transform the mysql methods to return a promise. https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original

There are node mysql packages, that wrap all the call to return promises instead of requiring callback functions. In that case your code would look similar to your original code.

```
var mysql = require('promise-mysql-or-similar');
router.get('/products', async function (req, res, next) {
    const response = await sqlHandler.doQuery('SELECT * FROM product');
    res.status(response.status).json(response.data);
});


module.exports = {
doQuery: async function (query) {
    const connection = await mysql.createConnection(connectionData);
    try {
        await connection.connect();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return {
            status: 502,
            data: {error: {code: 502, message: "Database connection error."}}
        };
    }

    try {
        const data = await connection.query(query);
        if (results.length) {
            return {
                status: 200,
                data: {data: results}
            };
        } else {
            return {
                status: 404,
                data: {error: {code: 404, message: "Not Found"}}
            };
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return {
            status: 500,
            data: {error: {code: 500, message: "Internal server error"}}
        };
    } finally {
        try {
            connection.end();
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I try your code and I saw that promise-mysql doesn't have connection.connect() and connection.query methods. Any idea where could be my mistake?

Comment: It was only an example. You need to pick one of them and then follow their api docs for the correct methods.